# How do you make a checkbox that is non interactive and is only checked if variable is?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I need a script where, if a value is higher then an assigned value. A non-interactive checkbox checks itself to show the user that the value they inserted is higher.

Comment: Make it `disabled` and check/uncheck it from an `input` event handler on the other input. Please try and show us your attempted code if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should come with some code or the example that you have tried, still following example can you help you with your problem:
HTML

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/par409yx

```js
document.getElementById('boxText').onchange = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('boxText').value > 10)
    document.getElementById('box').checked = true
  else
    document.getElementById('box').checked = false
};
```

```html
<input id="box" type="checkbox" disabled/>
<input id="boxText" type="text" />
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('box').checked = document.getElementById('boxText').value > 10`